# Magento: can't use attribute weight in actions condition for shopping cart price rule

Tags: magento

The attribute `'weight'` is set to `'yes'` for `"Use for Promo Rule Conditions"`. And I can use `"Total Weight"` in the condition area. So it is taken for the whole cart.
But I want to use it for action conditions (tab `"Action"`). All attributes, which can used for promo rules appear under the section `"Product Attribute"`. Weight is not there. I also want the "weight" of some products for action condition.

```
(I use Magento 1.8.1.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, but it seams like you cannot use the `weight` attribute for the rule conditions and actions.
When checking if an attribute is valid for rules this method is called 
`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::isAllowedForRuleCondition`

```
public function isAllowedForRuleCondition()
{
    $allowedInputTypes = array('text', 'multiselect', 'textarea', 'date', 'datetime', 'select', 'boolean', 'price');
    return $this->getIsVisible() && in_array($this->getFrontendInput(), $allowedInputTypes);
}
```

This seams reasonable. Now the strange part.
The weight attribute has the frontend input `weight`.
You can see this by running this query on the db.

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'weight'.
```

Changing the `frontend_input` to `text` makes the attribute available in promo rules. But I can't tell you if this is a good idea or not.

Answer (score -1):

Late here but if anyone has this question again, the reason why weight can't be setup in Shoppin Cart Price Rule is that by default the option for "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" is set to NO if you were to change that then weight will show up as an option

Comment: the very first line of the question states it is set to Yes. And this single change is not sufficient for the weight attribute. Please try things before you suggest them. I'm here because I've set it to Yes, re-indexed, cleared caches, etc., and it still isn't showing up.